# How do I remove special symbols such as &nbsp; &amp; from the file?

Tags: bash, unix, sed, tr

I've been trying to clean up my huge xml file (> 6gb) with `tr` util. The goal is to get rid of all invalid characters and also to get rid of such things as `&nbsp;`, `&amp;`, `&gt;` and etc.

Here is my current implementation:

```
cat input.xml | tr -dc '[:print:]' > output.xml
```

But it only removes invalid characters. Do you have any suggestions how to achieve it with `tr` util?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `tr` probably won't work

`tr` is only for replacing individual characters or character classes. Your examples `&nbsp;`, `&amp;`, and `&gt;` are strings. We'll need another tool.

### Here's an example with `perl`

```
$ cat input.xml
<xml><tag>&nbsp;hello&amp;, &gt;world!</tag></xml>
$ cat input.xml | perl -p -e 's/&.*?;//g'
<xml><tag>hello, world!</tag></xml>
```

**Explanation:**

```
perl -p -e 's/&.*?;//g'

perl -------------------- Run a perl program
     -p ----------------- Sets up a loop around our program
        -e -------------- Use what comes next as a line of our program
           's/&.*?;//g' - Our program, which is a perl regular expression.
                        - Explanation below:


           ' ------------ Quotes prevent shell expansion/interpolation.
            s ----------- Start a string substitution.
             / ---------- Use '/' as the command separator.
              & --------- Matches literal ampersand (&),
               . -------- followed by any character (.),
                * ------- any number of times (*),
                 ?; ----- until the next semicolon (?;).
                   // --- Replaces the matching text with the characters between the slashes (i.e. nothing at all)
                     g -- Allows matching the pattern multiple times per line
                      ' - Quotes prevent shell expansion/interpolation
```

Note that I'm assuming a pattern of [AMPERSAND(&), *SOMETHING*, SEMICOLON(;)] based on the example strings you provided.

You could extend that program to also remove your invalid characters, but I'd just continue to use `tr` for that. It's faster at least on my system.

### So putting it all together you get

```
cat input.xml | perl -p -e 's/&.*?;//g' | tr -dc '[:print:]' > output.xml
```

Comment: "?; ----- until the next semicolon (?;)." That might not be the best way to describe what's happening. The question mark makes the `.*` non-greedy. I'm gonna leave what I have since it's terse and does accurately describe the pattern overall.

Answer (score 0):

A character escape is a way of representing a character in source code using only ASCII characters. In HTML you can escape the euro sign € in the following ways.

```
Format  Name
&#x20AC;    hexadecimal numeric character reference
&#8364; decimal numeric character reference
&euro;  named character reference
```

In CSS syntax you would use one of the following.

```
Format  Notes
\20AC   must be followed by a space if the next character is one of a-f, A-F, 0-9
\0020AC must be 6 digits long, no space needed (but can be included)
```

A trailing space is treated as part of the escape, so use 2 spaces if you actually want to follow the escaped character with space. If using escapes in CSS identifiers, see the additional rules below.

Because you should use UTF-8 for the character encoding of the page, you won't normally need to use character escapes. You may, however, find them useful to represent invisible or ambiguous characters or characters that would otherwise interact in undesirable ways with the surrounding source code or text.

Answer (score -1):

open the file in Notepad++ and use replace option.

Comment: The xml is huge (> 6GB), it is not possible.